# Find pattern of a string, assigning to new variable in r

Tags: r, string

I have the following data

```
Mydata <- data_frame(
    myfield = c("ABC MUVBC82668689230230",
             "C3 MVBT7927979279279.",
             "t4 MUDW0348737237907023.",
             "D18 MVGJH979247979027903")
  )
```

I'm trying to extract the part of the string that starts with "MU" and "MV", creating a new variable to save the result. The desirable result would be:

```
MUVBC82668689230230
MVBT7927979279279
MUDW0348737237907023
MVGJH979247979027903
```

What I've tried so far:

```
pattern <- str_locate(Mydata$myfield, "\\d+\\-\\d+MU|\\d+\\-\\d+MV")

mydata$myfield2 <- str_extract(mydata$myfield2, pattern)

 Mydata <- Mydata %>%
            mutate(myfield2 = str_sub(Mydata$myfield2, pattern))

Mydata <- Mydata %>%
    mutate(myfield2= str_extract(myfield, pattern = "MV\\d+"))

 Mydata <- Mydata %>%
        mutate(myfield2 = str_extract_all("(?<=^| )(MU|MV).*?(?=$| )"))

Mydata <- Mydata %>%
    mutate(myfield2= str_extract(myfield, "Mv\\d+(_[A-Z]+)*"))
```

I usually use substr() but in my data, the pattern does not always start in the same position. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Mydata %>% 
       mutate(myfield = str_remove_all(myfield, ".*\\s+|\\.$"))
```

or with `str_extract`

```
Mydata %>% 
      mutate(myfield = str_extract(myfield, "\\bM[UV][[:alnum:]]+"))
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#  myfield             
#  <chr>               
#1 MUVBC82668689230230 
#2 MVBT7927979279279   
#3 MUDW0348737237907023
#4 MVGJH979247979027903
```

Note that some of the patterns in the OP's code wouldn't match because `"MV\\d+"` implies one or more digits after the 'MV' which is not the case

Comment: Thank you! Amazing and simple solution. Being new in r, I feel like I'm always complicating things.

Comment: In my real database, the outcome is extracting only the first 4 letters. Is there a way to set a variable size?

Comment: @DanielleTravassos. Can you show some values iin the real database.  Do they have. values other than alpha numeric as we used `[[:alnum:]]+`

Comment: Yes, they have spaces, (), [], and .. If the symbol is after the MU, MV, I should keep. Sorry that I haven't mentioned. I thought it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @DanielleTravassos In that case, may be `str_extract(myfield, "\\bM[UV].*$")`

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. I just replaced "\\bM[UV][[:alnum:]]+" with  "\\bM[UVvu][[:all:]]+" and it worked as well. Fantastic! Thank you